# Unable to get the Username for the current user inside my repository model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following to create logs information inside my repository method:-

```
var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;

var auditinfo = IntiateAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "DELETE").ActionID, tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "Server").AssetTypeID, currentUser, server.ServerID);
```

But I am unable to get the values of the `User.Identity.Name` inside my repository method, while I can do so inside my controller action methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can't because you need to reference the `HttpContext`. If you do this inside your repository, you will be able to:

```
string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

However, I would stay away from this since you will be required to reference System.Web in your repository classes which should be part of a total different project and should not even have a reference to System.Web to begin with.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so i need to pass the Username from my controller to my repository ? and what is the problem of including System.WEb inside my repository ?

Comment: @Asp.netmvcAsp.netmvc Imagine a scenario where you want to use your repository classes in another project, say a Winforms app. If you add a dependency to System.Web that means that your Winforms app will also require a reference to System.Web. Not only that, by calling `HttpContext.Current...` inside your repository, your code will break under a Winforms app because there's no `HttpContext` any more as there's no Web Request of any kind. You should avoid this sort of thing to maximize code reuse. Read about separation of concerns.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so the only way is to retrieve the current username from my action methods, and then pass the string to my repository?

Comment: It's not the only way since I already showed you how to do it, I am just letting you know that it's cleaner if you pass the username from the Controller.